# Как реализовать конвертацию валют в интернет магазине?

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите, как можно реализовать конвертацию валют в интернет магазине на битриксе? в стандартном модуле цены ничего не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существуют готовые модули, которые позволяют реализовать задуманное. Переписывать здесь код молулей нет смысла

Для примера готовый модуль на момент публикации комментария доступен по ссылке https://github.com/dimabresky/travelsoft.currency

Comment: не получается установить данный модуль

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Ошибки какие-то валятся или что?